# Posting to twitter using Flash/Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, twitter

I am trying to post a "tweet" to my twitter using Flex (using the Flex 3.5 SDK and Flex Builder 4 if that makes any difference).  On an mxml file I've created a button simply to make it easy to call an AS3 function, and in the function, I'm making a URL request.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, because my tweet ain't posting. I got these variables in the curl request provided by Twitter themselves, which actually worked.  My guess is that I'm formatting something incorrectly, but I don't know what that is....Thank you very much for any help you might provide.  Here is the code I'm using: 
EDIT: I would like to clarify that I already have the appropriate authorization keys and such (as I made a Coldfusion script to handle that).  I do not need help with authorization, just posting.

```
var postTO:URLRequest=new URLRequest("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json");
var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables(
"include_entities=true&status=Maybe+he%27ll+finally+fiasdfasdfmnnd+his+kekjhjkys.+%23peterfalk&trim_user=true"+"&"+
    "status=Maybe+he%27ll+finally+fiasdfasdfmnnd+his+kekjhjkys.+%23peterfalk"+"&"+
    "trim_user=true"+"&"+
    "oauth_consumer_key=<myOauthConsumerKey>"+"&"+
    "oauth_nonce=<myOauthNonce>"+"&"+
    "oauth_signature=<myOauthSignature>"+"&"+
    "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"+"&"+
    "oauth_timestamp=1331137102"+"&"+
    "oauth_token=<myOAuthToken>"+"&"+
    "oauth_version=1.0");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

postTO.data=params;
postTO.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
try {
    loader.load(postTO);
} catch (error:Error) {
    trace("Unable to load requested document.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Review the [crossdomain.xml](https://api.twitter.com/crossdomain.xml) file for the domain your accessing:

```
<cross-domain-policy xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
 <allow-access-from domain="twitter.com"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="api.twitter.com"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="search.twitter.com"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="static.twitter.com"/>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.twitter.com" headers="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Unless you are working for twitter and/or have access to serve your SWF off any of the allowed domains; you won't be able to build a browser based app that accesses these URLs directly from Flash  You'll have to build a proxy in the server side language of your choice.

Comment: I actually already had a file like that setup.  I can't seem to get it posted even using Coldfusion, making me think I must have some sort of  the formatting incorrect.

Comment: That is possible.  Remember that the crossdomain.xml file has to be on the server being accessed by Flash; not the server using the SWF. You'll have to get Twitter to change their crossdomain.xml file.  But, if ColdFusion can't access the URLs, then the problem is probably not cross domain security; but that would be a completely different question.